I have a question about local ring of specialization.
Let $X$ be scheme, let $x_1 \in X$. Let $x_0$ in $Z = \{x_1\}^{-}$ with reduced induced structure.
Then $Z$ is integral scheme. Let $R$ be local ring at $x_0$ on $Z$, let $k(x_1) = \mathcal{O}_{x_1,Z}/m_{x_1}$ where $m_{x_1}$ is maximal ideal in $\mathcal{O}_{x_1,Z}$
Then quotient field $K$ of $R$ is isomorphic to $k(x_1)$.
I don't know why $K \cong k(x_1)$.
If necessary assume that $X$ is noether.

Have you looked at any of the related questions? This one seems like it might help you, for instance.
